# 404 Error when building map

Tags: path-analyzer

My path analyzer doesn't have any data. it is showing me like the image below. Could I know how to redeploy the map and rebuild the historical data?

[image: Path-Analyzer issue]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try going to `https://your-domain/sitecore/admin/PathAnalyzer.aspx`

On this page you will find an option to perform **Historic Map Rebuild**.

> This process will rebuild all currently deployed maps from historic
> data in XDB. Depending on the number of interactions in XDB and the
> processing power, this could be a very expensive operation. Important:
> This feature is not expected to work in setups where processing server
> is separated from the reporting server. Please refer to the Knowledge
> Base for more details.